# Chosing the right charger: MacBook7,1 White A1324

Tags: charging, power, magsafe

I bought a used MacBook with identifier `MacBook7,1`, it's the white 2010 version (A1342). However, it already came with an off-brand charger and the text on it has gone washed off it seems, so I can not reliably tell which charger I would have to buy.

What I do know: I have to use MagSafe 1. According to a datasheet, it may as well be 60W.

Now, I have seen some bricks with USB-C to MagSafe 1 cables and additional USB ports - which would be handy to charge additional devices when on the go. But I am afraid of accidentially picking the wrong wattage.

What do I have to look out for, exactly, when picking a charger? I also live in Germany, if this is any important in terms of outlet, power delivery and alike. I'm a software-, not a hardware guy :)

Comment: Are you saying your current charger doesn't work?  Or you don't trust it and want to buy a new one?

Comment: It does work, but I do not completely trust it either. I'd like to buy a new and possibly more functional charger to replace it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can buy one [here](https://www.reichelt.com/de/en/apple-60w-magsafe-power-adapter-apple-mc461z-a-p119818.html?ARTICLE=119818&&r=1). It is original charger and it works well. Why do you need type c I can not understand

All you need to know about the charger is: voltage, socket type, magsafe version

Comment: Can you add some detail to address the "What do I have to look out for, exactly, when picking a charger" part of the question? This would make the answer more useful to users from other parts of the world.

Comment: @nohillside did it

Comment: I have a variety of devices that partially use USB-C. I had originally found [this cable (German Amazon)](https://www.amazon.de/waterfaill-WATERFAIL-C-Kabel-USB-Ladekabel-Kompatibel/dp/B07TVCH8X1/ref=sr_1_3?__mk_de_DE=ÅMÅŽÕÑ&keywords=usb+c+magsafe+1&qid=1575468575&sr=8-3) and was curious if I could find a charger that would allow me to charge my MacBook, iPhone and posissibly other devices such as a Switch, Apple Watch and alike. Looks like I will have to carry two chargers, as my search has not been successful so far...unfortunately.

Comment: @IngwiePhoenix yes, unfortunately you need to bring a lot of cables... It is a big problem for me also, because I need to bring a lot of cables, adapters, etc :D

Answer (score 1):

[This Apple page](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201700) will help you select the correct Apple charger. The charger for your MacBook appears to be a 60w MagSafe with "L" style connector.